# Why is unit testing harder in MVC than in MVP and MVVM

Tags: android, model-view-controller, mvvm, mvp, android-mvvm

I've been doing some research on pros and cons of MVC/MPV/MVVM and one common theme is that MVC is harder to unit test than MVP and MVVM but I don't fully understand why.

From my current understanding, in MVC, the view is dependent on the model and and controller so to test the view, both the controller and the model must be mocked. How is MVP/MVVM improve on this?

Comment: I understood it this way: in MVVM, since all the business logic should be inside ViewModel and View(activity,fragment) only responsible for updating UI based on data emitted by ViewModel, you can test all the business login in isolation.

Comment: https://www.angularminds.com/blog/article/mvc-vs-mvp-mvvm.html

Comment: https://medium.com/@sreeharikv112/android-unit-testing-clean-code-architecture-with-mvvm-73eb2992cab7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MVC, There is no separate component to handle UI or Presentation logic. Most of the time, it is written in View layer (Eg. Activity). You have to depend on frameworks like [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) which can understand Android ecosystem while writing unit tests. This makes difficult to unit test presentation logic. The other two patterns (MVP, MVVM) focus on decoupling Android dependencies with the help of interfaces and event driven pattern which simplifies unit testing. [This](https://medium.com/upday-devs/android-architecture-patterns-part-1-model-view-controller-3baecef5f2b6) blog explains more in detail.

I would suggest to explore [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide) and [Clean architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) for building highly modularized and testable application.

Comment: Can you describe more how Roboelectric makes life difficult in MVC?

Answer (score 5):

`MVVM` is the best choice for implementing unit tests compared with `MVP` and `MVC` because you can write test cases for both the `ViewModel` and `Model` layer without the need to reference the View and mock its objects.

`MVP` is also a good architecture pattern but its weakness compared with `MVVM` is you have reference to the View in your Presenter layer so you need to struggle with views reference in your Presenter unit tests.

`MVC` testing is almost like `MVP` but its main problem is that not only you have access to `View` in the `Controller` layer but you have access to the `Model` layer in your `View` as well that makes your testing harder.

Overall, as much as your code be decoupled writing unit tests is easier and MVVM architecture provides this decoupling to a great extent.

Comment: VM and Presenter are exactly same in functioning. Then what does that mean, " with MVVM is you have reference to the View in your Presenter layer so you need to struggle with views reference in your Presenter unit tests"?